# Entity Framework CTP 5 - Code First Mappings - Can't map properly an enum list

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I have the following

```
[DataContractAttribute]
public class Animal
{
    [Key]
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Id")]
    [DataMember()]
    public Guid Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "AnimalType")]
    [DataMember()]
    public List<AnimalType> AnimalType
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
 }
```

And i map it through the code first approach with EF to tables

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Animal>().ToTable("Animal");
```

As you see I have not performed some complex mapping, but the List of AnimalType enumerations did not get mapped automatically to any columns/tables in the DB. Do i need to add some extra code to the model builder to control the mapping of an enumeration list ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of EF CTP5, enums are *not* supported yet. The team announced that they are going to fully support enums in their next RTM version which is targeted to be released on the first quarter of 2011.

Comment: It seems that the Redmond guys have a hard time figuring out how to cast enums to ints and back, as there will be no enum support in EF 4.1. They now claim support will be added in vNext (4.2 or whatever). Source: http://reddevnews.com/blogs/data-driver/2011/03/entity-framework-code-first-no-enum.aspx

Comment: Looks like supporting Enums require changes to the core EF libraries shipped with .Net 4.0. which they can’t do it in EF 4.1 because they are not changing the core library.

Answer (score 1):

I know for the longest time, enums weren't supported by EF, though I don't know if that is still the case or not.

Either way, I think there is a general problem with having EF handle a list of a type other than another entity.  What is the primary key?  What is the value?  Should it try to store the data in one column or create a separate table and create a foreign key constraint?  These are questions that will likely need to be answered before your model can be converted into a database schema.

Comment: Yes.. i agree with your thoughts, and of course there are many pending questions.. but i think that this lack of support is pretty bad for EF, since developers use enums extensively, and it should be a top priority on their backlog.