# Overriding EF CodeFirst Generated Database

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a C# project that uses the EF CodeFirst approach.  My problem is how EF is interpreting my classes and generating the database tables.  EF is inferring too many things and my resulting db is not the way I would like. Specifically, it is generating additional id columns in one of my mapping classes.

Here are my POCO classes:

```
    public partial class Attribute
    {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<EntityAttribute> EntityAttributes {get;set;}
    }

    public partial class Grant
    {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<EntityAttribute> EntityAttributes {get;set;}
    }

    public partial class Donor
    {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<EntityAttribute> EntityAttributes {get;set;}
    }

    public enum EntityTypeEnum
    {
    Grant = 1,
    Donor = 2
    }

    public partial class EntityAttribute
    {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int EntityId {get;set;}
    public int AttributeId {get;set;}
    public int EntityTypeId {get;set;}
    public EntityTypeEnum EntityType
    {
       get{return (EntityTypeEnum)this.EntityTypeId;}
       set{this.EntityTypeId = (int)value;}
    }
    public virtual Grant Grant {get;set;}
    public virtual Donor Donor {get;set;}
}
```

My mapping classes are typical but here is the EntityAttributeMap class:

```
public partial class EntityAttributeMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<EntityAttribute>
{
public EntityAttributeMap()
{
this.ToTable("EntityAttribute");
this.HasKey(ea => ea.Id);
this.Property(ea => ea.EntityTypeId).IsRequired();
this.Ignore(ea => ea.EntityType);

this.HasRequired(ea => ea.Grant)
    .WithMany(g => g.EntityAttributes)
    .HasForeignKey(ea => ea.EntityId);

this.HasRequired(ea => ea.Donor)
    .WithMany(d => d.EntityAttributes)
    .HasForeignKey(ea => ea.EntityId);

this.HasRequired(ea => ea.Attribute)
    .WithMany(a => a.EntityAttributes)
    .HasForeignKey(ea => ea.AttributeId)
}
}
```

All of my unit tests perform as expected. However, the table EntityAttribute gets rendered with DonorId and GrantId columns.  I don't want this as I actually have dozens of other "EntityTypes" that will be used for this scenario.  That is why I chose the EntityTypeEnum class.

What am I doing wrong?  Or is there another way I should be mapping these so EF handles things the way I want.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The EF doesn't support enums at all, as of V4 CTP 5. They might be included in the next release.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452201/entity-framework-ctp-5-code-first-mappings-cant-map-properly-an-enum-list)

Having said that, the schema looks (to me; it's not clear from your post, and your intentions may be different) too close to an [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) for my comfort. For the usual reasons (Google it) I dislike these, and wouldn't want that sort of model even with `enum` support in the EF.

Why not map to another entity type instead of an enum?

If you ask a question in the form of "Here are my business needs; what is the best schema for this?" you may get a better answer.

Comment: I guess I am veering towards EAV as you suggested.  I was only trying to be efficient.  Given that I will have numerous entities mapped to my Attribute table, would you suggest a separate mapping table for each entity/attribute combination OR multiple entity id columns in one mapping table.  The downside of this I guess would be lots of nulls.  Also, thanks for the question framing suggestions.

Comment: Lots of nulls may not be a problem. SQL Server 2008+, e.g., lets you declare columns `SPARSE` which tells the server "optimize for mostly NULLs".

Comment: Oh, and regarding one table vs. many, read up on TPH vs. TPT inheritance modeling in the EF. Even though you're not doing inheritance *per se,* the performance considerations are the same.

Comment: Thanks Craig.  I'll probably go for the one table and optimize for NULLS (I did not know that about SQL Server).  This is a back office application that won't have more than a few dozen users at the most.  However, I will check out your reading suggestions.  Thanks again.